# Is an R object of class "POSIXlt" a "list" or not?

Tags: r, list

By the [documentation of the class POSIXlt](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) an object of class POSIXlt is a named list.
And indeed:

```
> tm <- strptime( "24-12-2015 05:28:12", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC" )
> class(tm)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 

> tm$sec
[1] 12

> tm$min
[1] 28

> tm$hour
[1] 5

> tm$mday
[1] 24

> tm$mon
[1] 11

> tm$year
[1] 115

> tm$wday
[1] 4

> tm$yday
[1] 357

> tm$isdat
NULL

> tm$zone
NULL

> tm$gmtoff
NULL
```

The [documentation of the class list](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html) says that `is.list(tm)` is TRUE if and only if `tm` is a list or a pairlist,
and `is.pairlist(tm)` is TRUE if and only if `tm` is a pairlist or NULL.

```
> is.list(tm)
[1] TRUE
> is.pairlist(tm)
[1] FALSE
```

Hence `tm` must be a list.

But "list" is not a superclass of "POSIXlt":

```
> is(tm)
[1] "POSIXlt"  "POSIXt"   "oldClass"
> extends("POSIXlt")
[1] "POSIXlt"  "POSIXt"   "oldClass"
```

`extends` negates the the question if "POSIXlt" extents "list", the answer is not even "maybe":

```
> extends("POSIXlt","list")
[1] FALSE
```

Furthermore,

```
> is("POSIXlt","list")
[1] FALSE
> is(tm,"list")
[1] FALSE
```

By the [documentation of `is`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/is.html) this means that `tm` cannot be treated as from "list". In particular `tm` is not a list.
But if `tm` cannot be treated as from "list", why does `as` succeed in coercing `tm` to a list?
`as(tm.list` is doubtless a list, whereas `as.list(tm)` and `tm` are identical:

```
> as(tm,"list")
[[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 28

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] 24

[[5]]
[1] 11

[[6]]
[1] 115

[[7]]
[1] 4

[[8]]
[1] 357

[[9]]
[1] 0

> class(as(tm,"list"))
[1] "list"
> is.list(as(tm,"list"))
[1] TRUE
> is(as(tm,"list"),"list")
[1] TRUE
> identical(tm,as.list(tm))
[1] TRUE
```

`as(tm,"list")` does have the components specified in the documentation of the class POSIXlt, but the names are gone.

What does it mean to be a list? Is `tm` a list or not?

Answer (score 7):

It is a named list with a `c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")` class and a `tzone` attribute:

> POSIXlt = Named list + class + tzone attribute

In fact, we can build up or manufacture such an object from a named list `L` by adding the `class` and `tzone` attribute like this:

```
L <- list(sec = 12, min = 28L, hour = 5L, mday = 24L, mon = 11L, 
    year = 115L, wday = 4L, yday = 357L, isdst = 0L)

tm0 <- L # start with list L
class(tm0) <- c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")  # add class
attr(tm0, "tzone") <- "UTC"  # add tzone

tm <- strptime( "24-12-2015 05:28:12", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC" )
identical(tm0, tm)
## [1] TRUE
```

We can recover the named list `L` from `tm` by removing the `class` and the `tzone` attribute:

```
tm <- strptime( "24-12-2015 05:28:12", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC" )  # start w tm
L0 <- unclass(tm)  # remove class
attr(L0, "tzone") <- NULL  # remove tzone
identical(L0, L)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Before I start this answer, I would ask: *why do you want to know?*  In particular, I think you could get better advice here on a more specific question of "I want to treat an object of type `POSIXlt` as a list in  the following context: will that work?  Or even, "under what circumstances will treating an object of type `POSIXlt` as a list get me in trouble?"  It's not *unreasonable* to ask for clarification on the formal semantics of R, but you'll probably discover that it's a bit murky.

I *think* (but hope that someone more knowledgeable will chime in, in which case I may delete this) that you've stumbled into some of the murky undercurrents of R object-orientation, i.e. that older/built-in classes don't always follow all of the semantics in the naively expected way (although sufficiently careful reading of the documentation may show that it is *technically* correct). In particular, I'm sure that `extends()` and `is()` work as (naively) expected for S4 objects, I'm less sure about objects with S3 methods, and I'm the most uncertain about built-in classes.

FWIW `data.frame` shares some of the same confusion: is it a list or not?  (the class does `extend` lists, but doesn't inherit from them ...)

```
dd <- data.frame("xys")
is(dd,"list")
## [1] FALSE
extends("data.frame","list")
## [1] TRUE
inherits(dd,"list")
## [1] FALSE
is.list(dd)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I would like to understand R. Therefore my question.

Comment: It depends on [what the meaning of the word "is" is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4XT-l-_3y0).